# unreachable-code In C++11, what may cause this?

Tags: c++, class, generics, operator-overloading

I wrote the following code in Clion for my C++11:

```
Matrix<T> &Matrix<T>::operator=(const Matrix<T> &matrix) {
    if (this == &matrix) {
        return *this;
    }
    int matrix_size = matrix.size();
    T *temp = new T[matrix_size];
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix_size; ++i) {
            temp[i] = data[i];
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        delete[] temp;
        throw;
    }
    delete[] data;
    data = temp;
    dimensions = matrix.dimensions;
    return *this;
}
```

But it shows me that what's written inside catch is an unreachable-code, why is that?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Copying a `T` could throw.

Comment: My guess is since templates are evaluated at compile time you didn't actually use a type for T that has a copy operation that throws and the compiler managed to see that. Maybe try using something for T that potentially throws in it's copy assignment operator and see if that makes the warning go away. But it's just a guess.

Comment: FWIW, if you use a `std::vector` instead of manually creating an array using `new` you don't even need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Clion is probably wrong. It clearly isn't unreachable if T throws on copy assignment.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89bdf369c396ca88)

The only way I could see the assessment being correct is if it checks every instanciation of `Matrix` and makes sure, in each case, that the type used doesn't throw. However, I still wouldn't agree with it since `Matrix` could be used somewhere Clion doesn't have access to.

Note that you shouldn't code like this anyway. Use a `std::vector` instead of a raw pointer and dynamic allocations. Then you don't need the try-catch block: `std::vector` takes care of that for you.

Also, I believe you meant to write `temp[i] = matrix.data[i];` in the loop.

Comment: Yep, CLion has been giving me a bunch of unreachable errors whenever I do anything with try/catch. Super strange.